# Combining evidence using Dempster-Shafer theory

Tags: probability, bayesian, text-mining

Can someone post a simple explanation of Dempster-Shafer theory? There are lot of links available but the reading material in those sites is academic in nature and time consuming to read and comprehend.

What I'm trying to do is calculate similarity scores between two words. I am using 3 different similarity measures. Next, I need to combine these scores using Dempster-Shafer theory.